# Issue with catalog price rules in Magento 1.9.3.2

Tags: php, magento

I am facing issues with catalog price rules in Magento 1.9.3.2.

To replicate scenario here's the steps we are assigning.

1. I have created two Catalog Price Rules for two custmer types of groups "NOT LOGGED IN" and "SPECIAL".
2. I have a product which has price $77.00, sku - product1

Now Rule 1 will have following set of conditions:
- Priority - 1
- Applied to two customer groups
"NOT LOGGED IN"
"SPECIAL"
- sku - product1 (SKU matches product1)
- Apply - by percent
- Discount amount - 54 (54%)
- Stop Further Rules Processing - yes
After activating only this discount rule I'm getting price on Product as $35.42

Now Rule 2 will have following set of conditions:
- Priority - 2
- Applied to two customer groups
"NOT LOGGED IN"
"SPECIAL"
- sku - product2 (SKU matches product1)
- Apply - by percent
- Discount amount - 40 (40%)
- Stop Further Rules Processing - yes

After activating only this discount rule i'm getting price on Product is $46.20.

Now when i have both of the above rules active together, product1 should show $35.42 (as it should exit after rule 1 and it's value), however i'm seeing $35.00 (rounding off last 2 digits for some reasons).

I feel that many others might have faced this issues, and might have solution. Looking forward your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've just checked it, and I almost was convinced that it is an issue. But, I've discovered that one of the rules which come with Magento sample data made me an issue with the price.

So, I suggest to you to disable all other price rules and leave only your two rules. Then click on Apply Rules, and check the price on the frontend.